# Custom data loading very slow [indexing | Processing files]

Tags: swiftui

I need your help with how to solve my custom data slow loading. I create a collection of my native song lyrics as data. Unexpectedly, there are over 500 songs, and when I try to load in my app, it is crazily slow. It took about over 5 minutes to display my lyric. Please help me with how do I solve it. I read about background threading, but I don't know it is related to my problem since I am not downloading any data. Especially, the slow loading significantly begins when the songs are over 150, and all the songs are hardcoded by me. Below is my code and thank you in advance.
New update: Now, my Xcode stuck at `Indexing | Processing files` and asked me to Force Quit Xcode Application. This is my original Lyric file. Feel free to test it. https://github.com/siantung/Hymn-iOS

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Lyric: Identifiable {
    
    let id: Int
    let zoTitle: String
    let engTitle: String
    let key: String
    let musicStyle: String
    let translation: String
    let verse1: String
    var verse2: String?
    var verse3: String?
    var verse4: String?
    var verse5: String?
    var verse6: String?
    var preChorus: String?
    var chorus: String?
    var bridge: String?
    let isFavoriteSong: Bool
    let isNotedSong: Bool
    let isHighlightedSong: Bool
    let isBookMarkedSong: Bool
    let isSharedSong: Bool
    let isCopySong: Bool
    
}

public struct LyricList {
    
    static var hymnLa = [
        
        Lyric(id: 1,
              
            zoTitle: "Pasian Phatna",
            
            engTitle: "Praise God, from whom All Blessings Flow",
            
            key: "Key: G",
            
            musicStyle: "",
            
            translation: "S.S. 9",
            
            verse1: "Thupha kheempeuh hong pia Pasian \nPhat un, leitung mi khempeuh aw, \nPhat un vantung mi honpi'n zong; \nPhat un Pa, Ta le Kha Siangtho.",
            
            isFavoriteSong: false,
            isNotedSong: false,
            isHighlightedSong: false,
            isBookMarkedSong: false,
            isSharedSong: false,
            isCopySong: false),
            
            
            
        Lyric(id: 2,
              
            zoTitle: "Itna Kumpi, Ka Tuu-Cing Pa",
            
            engTitle: "The King of Love My Shephaerd Is (Dominus Regit Me)",
            
            key: "Key: G",
            
            musicStyle: "",
            
            translation: "C.W. 169, S.H. 250",
            
            verse1: "Itna Kumpi, ka tuu-cing pa, \nAma hoih na sia ngei lo, \nA mi suak leng sapna om lo, \nTawntung Ama mi hi ta.",
            
            verse2: "Nuntakna tui a luanna ah, \nTat khiatsa ka kha tonpih, \nLo no naah hong paipih hi, \nVantung an tawh hong vaak hi.",
            
            verse3: "Khuamial sihna kuam sung lau lo, \nKei kiang Topa Na om hi, \nKa lung nuam sak, Na ciangkhut in, \nLam hong hilh singlamteh in.",
            
            verse4: "Ni sim tawntung kizom sual in, \nNa hoihna kipelh ngei lo, \nTuucing siampa, Nang kong phat hi, \nTawntung nangma innpi sung Amen.",
            
            isFavoriteSong: false,
            isNotedSong: false,
            isHighlightedSong: false,
            isBookMarkedSong: false,
            isSharedSong: false,
            isCopySong: false),

        // There are over 500 songs 
    ]
}
       
import SwiftUI

class SongViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var songs: [Lyric] = []
    
    init() {
        loadSong()
    }
    
    private func loadSong() {
        let datas = LyricList.hymnla
        songs = datas
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var vm = SongViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
            
                ForEach(vm.songs) { song in
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("\(song.id)")
                        
                        Text(song.zoTitle)
                        
                        Text(song.engTitle)
                        
                        Text(song.verse1)
                        
                        if let cho = song.chorus {
                            Text(cho)
                        }
                        
                        if let v2 = song.verse2 {
                            Text(v2)
                        }
                        
                        if let v3 = song.verse3 {
                            Text(v3)
                        }
                        
                        if let v4 = song.verse4 {
                            Text(v4)
                        }
                        
                        if let v5 = song.verse5 {
                            Text(v5)
                        }
                    }
                    .forgroundColor(.primary)
                    .padding()
                }
            }

        }.environmentObject(vm)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContenView()
            .environmentObject(SongViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works well for me, no delay in loading, no lag in scrolling. 
The delay must be in some other code your not showing.

On macos 12.1-beta, using xcode 13.2-beta, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. 
Tested on real devices.

Comment: I assume that is not the real versions of `loadSong` you are showing here. Where does your data come from, hardcoded, file on disk or downloaded or...?

Comment: Thanks for the commands and your help. The data are hardcoded, and I typed all the songs one by one. I really don't know the right way. @Joakim Danielson

Comment: @workingdog, I am always thankful for your help. In this example, I only provided two songs. There is no lag or slow loading until I reached over 150 songs.  But my computer fan starts exploding noises and loading is pretty slow after over 200 songs. I don't know it is normal because all the data(songs) are hardcoded.

Comment: I update my questions to a more readable. Thanks, everyone for your help.

Comment: my tests of your code consisted of 1000 random Lyrics, generated at the start using `.onAppear`.
I also tested reading 1000 Lyrics from file. As I said in my comment, no delay in loading, no lag in scrolling. I will have a look at your `original Lyric file`.

Comment: you are using the wrong approach to loading data. 
Do not put 18500 lines of code in `Lyric.swift`. This is your problem. Nobody does this. 
Put you data in a data file, then read the data and create your Lyric objects.
For example; make a json file with all your lyrics data as json in a file called Lyrics.json. Then read that json data and create a `[Lyric]` array of objects, and put that in the `SongViewModel` songs array.

Comment: Ok, again, thanks. Now, I know where to start.

Comment: Btw, is it possible to convert Swift to json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to

1. generate the json data from your "original" `Lyric.swift`.
2. read the json data back to your app.

First note the change `struct Lyric: Identifiable, Codable` to allow reading and making json data.

With your original LyricList in `Lyric.swift`, create the data file "Lyrics.json"
using `vm.writeToFile(lyrics: vm.songs, fileName: "lyrics")` in `ContentView`. The file will be in ".../Library/Containers/.../Data/Applications/lyrics.json". Copy that file to your project folder, and use Xcode to add that file to your project.

Then delete your `Lyric.swift` code (or remove it from your xcode project).
This is what takes forever to compile.

Then comment out `vm.writeToFile(lyrics: vm.songs, fileName: "lyrics")` in `ContentView`
and un-comment `if let lyrics = vm.loadData(from: "lyrics") ....`

```
struct Lyric: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let zoTitle: String
    let engTitle: String
    let key: String
    let musicStyle: String
    let translation: String
    let verse1: String
    var verse2: String?
    var verse3: String?
    var verse4: String?
    var verse5: String?
    var verse6: String?
    var preChorus: String?
    var chorus: String?
    var bridge: String?
    let isFavoriteSong: Bool
    let isNotedSong: Bool
    let isHighlightedSong: Bool
    let isBookMarkedSong: Bool
    let isSharedSong: Bool
    let isCopySong: Bool
}

class SongViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var songs: [Lyric] = []
    
    init() {
      // use this only once, when writeToFile in ContentView
      // then remove this and remove Lyric.swift
      songs = LyricList.hymnLa

    }
    
    func loadData(from file: String) -> [Lyric]? {
        do {
            if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "json") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                return try JSONDecoder().decode([Lyric].self, from: data)
            }
        } catch {
            print("----> error: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func writeToFile(lyrics: [Lyric], fileName: String) {
        do {
            let dir = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("json")
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(lyrics)
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("------> \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = SongViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(vm.songs) { song in
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("\(song.id)")
                        Text(song.zoTitle)
                        Text(song.engTitle)
                        Text(song.verse1)
                        if let cho = song.chorus { Text(cho) }
                        if let v2 = song.verse2 { Text(v2) }
                        if let v3 = song.verse3 { Text(v3) }
                        if let v4 = song.verse4 { Text(v4) }
                        if let v5 = song.verse5 { Text(v5) }
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
        }.environmentObject(vm)
            .onAppear {
                // loading data from file
//                if let lyrics = vm.loadData(from: "lyrics") {
//                    vm.songs = lyrics
//                }

                // writing data to file
                vm.writeToFile(lyrics: vm.songs, fileName: "lyrics")
                print("\n----> done writeToFile\n")
            }
    }
  
}
```

EDIT1: a slightly more compact version.

```
class SongViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var songs: [Lyric] = []
    
    init() {
        // use this only once, when writeToFile in ContentView
        // then remove this and remove Lyric.swift
        songs = LyricList.hymnLa
        
        // you can use this here instead of using it in ContentView .onAppear
        // loadData(from: "lyrics")
    }
    
    func loadData(from file: String) {
        do {
            if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "json") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                songs = try JSONDecoder().decode([Lyric].self, from: data)
            }
        } catch {
            print("----> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func writeToFile(fileName: String) {
        do {
            let dir = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("json")
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(songs)
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("------> \(error)")
        }
        print("\n----> done writeToFile\n")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = SongViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(vm.songs) { song in
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("\(song.id)")
                        Text(song.zoTitle)
                        Text(song.engTitle)
                        Text(song.verse1)
                        if let cho = song.chorus { Text(cho) }
                        if let v2 = song.verse2 { Text(v2) }
                        if let v3 = song.verse3 { Text(v3) }
                        if let v4 = song.verse4 { Text(v4) }
                        if let v5 = song.verse5 { Text(v5) }
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
        }.environmentObject(vm)
            .onAppear {
                // loading data from file
                // vm.loadData(from: "lyrics")
                
                // writing data to file
                vm.writeToFile(fileName: "lyrics")
            }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is unbelievable. I couldn't do it by myself. Thank you so much. Please don't delete your answer because I need to follow your instructions step by step.

Comment: updated `SongViewModel` `init()` with missing initial `songs = LyricList.hymnLa` when used to write to file.